# Why does this SQL code not work in Microsoft Access but works in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

This code will not work in Microsoft Access but it works in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. What can I do to make this work in Access? I keep getting a

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CAST(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * (1 + od.Discount) as decimal(10,2)) 'Order Total'.

```
Select TOP 5 
    c.CompanyName as 'Company Name', 
    CAST(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * (1 + od.Discount) as decimal(10, 2)) 'Order Total'
From 
    Customers as c
Join 
    Orders as o On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
Join 
    OrderDetails as od On o.OrderID = od.OrderID
Where 
    od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * (1 + od.Discount) > 5000 
    AND c.Country IN ('Austria', 'Denmark', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Sweden')
Order By 
    o.OrderDate desc
```

Comment: wich is the error?

Comment: @gurV It is an error with `cast`. I cannot figure out why though.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use CAST in Access... try with this options:

**Cint** -- cast to integer

**Clng** -- long

**Cdbl** -- double

**Csng** - single

**Cstr** - string

**Cbool** - boolean

**CDec** - Decimal

Example: `SELECT clng(fieldName) FROM tableName`

In your case:

```
Select TOP 5 
    c.CompanyName as 'Company Name', 
    CDec(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * (1 + od.Discount)) 'Order Total'
From 
    Customers as c
Join 
    Orders as o On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
Join 
    OrderDetails as od On o.OrderID = od.OrderID
Where 
    od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * (1 + od.Discount) > 5000 
    AND c.Country IN ('Austria', 'Denmark', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Sweden')
Order By 
    o.OrderDate desc
```

Hope this help!

Comment: ... and don't forget CDec to cast to decimal, which is the data type the OP is looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the CAST works OK in Access (if it exists). I would take the CAST out and change it for something like the CDec() function. You have to use one of the followings in general: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Answer (score 0):

The CAST and CONVERT column functions do not seem to work in MS Access.

Try the CInt or the CLng function, depending upon whether you want an integer (16 bit) or a long integer (32 bit).